# When a group is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

If $G$ is a finite group and has at most one subgroup of an arbitrary order (of course, dividing order of $G$) could we deduce that $G$ is cyclic ?

Comment: Any group has at least two sugbroups, they are trivial subgroups.

Comment: Yes, the claim is true, yet for its proof I'd need to use Euler's Totient Function. If you have already studied it then you can try it, and if you get stuck somewhere write back. You may also want to read the first two pages of the awesome book "A Course in Arithmetic", by J. P. Serre...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, something even stronger is true (the original question has already been answered in the comments).

Assume that $G$ is a finite group and let $\pi$ be the set of primes dividing $|G|$.

For each $p\in \pi$, let $n_p$ be the largest power of $p$ that divides $|G|$.

To conclude that $G$ is cyclic, it is enough to assume that $G$ has at most one subgroup of order $p^{n_p}$ for each $p\in \pi$ and that for each $p\in \pi$ there is a natural number $m_p$ with $1\leq m_p\leq n_p - 1$ such that $G$ has at most one subgroup of order $p^{m_p}$. Except that if $2\in \pi$ and $n_2\geq 3$ we need to require $m_2\geq 2$.

Proof: The first condition means that all Sylow subgroups are normal, so it suffices to show that all Sylow subgroups are cyclic.

But if a $p$-group of order $p^a$ has a unique subgroup of order $p^b$ for some $1\leq b\leq a-1$ then it is cyclic unless $p=2$, $b=1$ and the group is generalized quaternion (this is a standard result in $p$-group theory, and a reference can be found in for example Berkovich's book on groups of prime power order). This completes the proof due to our extra requirements when $2\in \pi$.

Comment: Can I ask for what we have shown the existance of a subgroup? I have found that every group, whose order is prime number, is cyclic.

Comment: @Novice Yes, that is correct, but I am not sure how it relates to this answer.

Comment: _But if a $p$-group of order $p^a$ has a unique subgroup of order $p^b$ for some $1\leq b\leq a-1$ then it is cyclic_. I don't know what was the aim of showing the existance of subgroup. Is it not sufficient that this $p$-group is of order $p^a$ so in the consequence cyclic?

Comment: @Novice Not all groups of prime power order are cyclic. Prime order and prime power order are not the same.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you know [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) and the fact that a cyclic group of order$~n$ has *exactly* one cyclic subgroup of order$~d$ whenever $d$ divides$~n$, then you can prove this by comparing the finite group$~G$ and the cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n=|G|$. For any $d$ one sees as follows that there can be no more elements of order$~d$ in$~G$ than there are in$~C_n$. In order to have any such elements at all in$~G$, one must have $d\mid n$ by Lagrange, and $G$ must have at least one cyclic subgroup of order$~d$ (spanned by such an element); but by hypothesis this is then the unique such cyclic subgroup of $G$, and all elements of order$~d$ are members of it. In the meantime $C_n$ also has a cyclic subgroup of order$~d$; the two cyclic subgroups contain equally many elements of order$~d$.

Now if there were no elements in $G$ of order$~n$, it would have stricly less elements than$~C_n$ (which does have elements of order$~n$); this would contradict $n=|G|$. By a group of order $n$ with an element of order$~n$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this proof from Keith Conrad’s handout about Sylow applications. Our argument has two steps: verify the theorem for groups of prime-power order and then use Sylow one to derive the general case from the prime-power case.
 Step 1: Let #G=$p^k$ where p is pr prime,$k≥1$, and assume G has at most one subgroup of each size. To show G is cyclic, let g be an element of G with maximal order. We want G=< g >.Pick any h belong to G, so h is a power of p by Lagrange. Let g have order $p^m$  and h have order $p^n$, so $n≤m$. Then $p^n$ divides $p^m$, so there is a subgroup of the cyclic group < g > with order $p^n$ .
Also < h > has order $p^n$, so our hypothesis that G has at most one subgroup per size implies < h > lies in < g >, so h belongs to . Therefore < g > contains G. (This argument was told to me by Trevor Hyde.)
Step 2: Let G be group with at most one subgroup per size. Therefore $n_p=1$ for all primes p. For different primes p and q dividing #G, the elements of
the p-Sylow and q-Sylow subgroup commute with each other.
Any subgroup of G has at most one subgroup of any size (otherwise G itself would have two subgroups of the same size), so by Step 1 the p-Sylow subgroup of G is cyclic. Choose a generator $g_p$ of the p-Sylow subgroup of G. These $g_p$ s commute as p varies, by the previous paragraph, and their orders are relatively prime, so the product of the $g_p $s has order equal to the product of the sizes of the Sylow subgroups of G. This product of sizes is #G, so G is cyclic.